# How to set sound for notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I copied the .mp3 file in assets. When notification raises, file is not playing

Could anyone please help me.

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///android_assets/alarm_951.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
   notifyDetails.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying your file to the assets folder copy it to resources/raw/ and then use

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mysound);
mBuilder.setSound(sound);
```