# How to set Preference fetched as String into URI

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch as resource mp3 file in URI from preference and setting it into Notification to play mp3 Notification sound. But it isn't working giving error

```
parse (java.lang.string) in URI cannot be applied
```

Below is code :
Setting

```
obj.setNotificationSound("android.resource://com.packagename.sampleapp/raw/pushsound");
```

Getting

```
String setnotificationsound = prefs.getNotificationSound(context);
Uri sound = Uri.parse(setnotificationsound);  //Received String as "R.raw.pushsound" 
            //but getting error (parse (java.lang.string) in URI cannot be applied)
b.setSound(sound);
```

Comment: "R.raw.pushsound"   is not a URI address

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16866504/2945811